# Serialization error with merged kafka stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have N Kafka topics containing the same value type. I wish to merge these topics into one, with throttled events per key.

Here's the code I have currently:

```
KStream<Long, Event> allEvents = null;
for (String topic : EventsTopics.split(",")) {
    KStream<Long, Event> events = builder.stream(topic,
            Consumed.with(longAvroSerde, EventsAvroSerde));

    if (allEvents == null) {
        allEvents = events;
    } else {
        allEvents = allEvents.merge(events);
    }
}

allEvents
    .groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(0)))
    .reduce((value1, value2) -> value2)
    .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()))
    .toStream()
    .peek((key, value) -> System.out.printf("key=%s, value=%s\n", key, value.toString()))
    .to(mergeTopic);
```

This works when there is only one topic. Here's a snip of the KStreamImpl:

```
allEvents = {KStreamImpl@1519} 
 repartitionRequired = false
 repartitionNode = null
 name = "KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000"
 keySerde = {PrimitiveAvroSerde@1514} 
 valSerde = {SpecificAvroSerde@1515} 
 subTopologySourceNodes = {Collections$SingletonSet@1521}  size = 1
 streamsGraphNode = {StreamSourceNode@1522} "StreamSourceNode{topicNames=[global_events_uat], topicPattern=null, consumedInternal=org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.ConsumedInternal@d721838b} StreamsGraphNode{nodeName='KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000', buildPriority=0, hasWrittenToTopology=false, keyChangingOperation=false, valueChangingOperation=false, mergeNode=false, parentNodes=[root]}"
 builder = {InternalStreamsBuilder@1523}
```

However when more than one topic have been included, there is a serialization error.

```
Exception in thread "merge-c30bd85c-2b6e-4460-ae3d-b7a5ffa117c5-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: stream-thread [merge-c30bd85c-2b6e-4460-ae3d-b7a5ffa117c5-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Failed to flush state store KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000003
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:453)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.prepareCommit(StreamTask.java:357)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.commit(TaskManager.java:955)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:851)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:714)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:510)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Avro type. Supported types are null, Boolean, Integer, Long, Float, Double, String, byte[] and IndexedRecord
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchemaUtils.getSchema(AvroSchemaUtils.java:121)
```

And here's how the merged KStreamImpl looks in the debugger:

```
allEvents = {KStreamImpl@1525} 
 repartitionRequired = false
 repartitionNode = null
 name = "KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000002"
 keySerde = null
 valSerde = null
 subTopologySourceNodes = {HashSet@1527}  size = 2
 streamsGraphNode = {ProcessorGraphNode@1528} "ProcessorNode{processorParameters=ProcessorParameters{processor class=class org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.PassThrough$PassThroughProcessor, processor name='KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000002'}} StreamsGraphNode{nodeName='KSTREAM-MERGE-0000000002', buildPriority=3, hasWrittenToTopology=false, keyChangingOperation=false, valueChangingOperation=false, mergeNode=true, parentNodes=[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000001]}"
 builder = {InternalStreamsBuilder@1529}
```

I'm quite a newbie with Kafka Streams, so not sure how to investigate. Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the `EventsAvroSerd` you are using and seems to be related to the schema registry -- thus not directly a KafkaStreams issue. -- The error says `Unsupported Avro type.` and comes from `ProcessorStateManager.flush` that tries to write into `KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000003`l thus, it's related to your `reduce()` step.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using cogroup. you would group each stream then create a cogrouped stream out of all the grouped streams. Then you can window and aggregate that stream. It is also more efficient than merging many streams then grouping them.

```
KTable<K, CG> cogrouped =
  grouped1
    .cogroup(aggregator1)
    .cogroup(grouped2, aggregator2)
    .cogroup(grouped3, aggregator3)
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(0)))
    .aggregate(initializer1, materialized1);
```

As for the serdes error sometimes when having multiple streams incoming it is hard for streams to verify the serdes to use and it falls back on the configuration's default. I would recommend that you make sure that is set correctly. it could be why they are null when you have more than one stream.